# Jquery UI resizeable autohide handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like the resize handle to show initially when the element is loaded. Then once the user has hovered over the red container I would like to invoke the autohide option on the handle. Therefore it will then have autohide behaviour from that point on.

I have set the code to apply the auto hide option on hover but for some reason it isn't working.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/12034/

```
// no auto hide intially
$('#resize').resizable({
  aspectRatio: true,
  //                autoHide: true,
  handles: {
    se: $('#resize').find('.resize_element')
  },
});

// apply autohide behaviour when container is first hovered over 
// not currently working though?
$( "#container" ).hover(function() {
  $('#resize').resizable( "option", "autoHide", true );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your .hover function a bit:

```
$( "#container" ).hover(function() {
$('.resize_element').hide()
}, function(){
$('.resize_element').show()
});
```

Working Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/12035/

And if you don't want the resizer to re-appear then remove the second function that brings it back.